# Find a bijection from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, cardinals

Find a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I was asked to find the bijection and I've gone in this following way :

Let,
$$(x,y,z) (\ne(0,0,0)) \in \mathbb{R}^3$$
$$(x,y,z) \to (\frac{1}{1+e^x},\frac{1}{1+e^y},\frac{1}{1+e^z}) \to (0.x_1x_2... ,0.y_1y_2... , 0.z_2z_2... ) \to (0.x_1y_1z_1x_2y_2z_2... ) = a \to \log(\frac{1}{a} -1)$$
And, $$f(0,0,0) = 0$$

Here, $$\frac{1}{1+e^x} \in (0,1)$$ and I am taking only one decimal representation of any real number in $(0,1)$.

So $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y,z) = \log(\frac{1}{a} -1)$ one-one map and onto also because I've considered unique decimal representation of a real number in $(0,1)$.

Am I correct? If not then can someone give any constructive bijection (Not geometrical)?

Comment: What’s your objection to geometry?

Comment: If $(x,y,z)=0$ then $a=0$, so you can't take $\log(1/a-1)$.

Comment: @David okay then for all $(x,y,z) \ne 0$ $f(x,y,z) = \log(\frac{1}{a}-1)$ and for $f(0,0,0) = 0$. Now is it a bijection?

Comment: I understand this may have been the construct used by Cantor when he was demonstrating that $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R$ are equinumerous. If it were me, I would be happy to go along with it, although I might have used something simpler to map between $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Prime no no, I honestly did make it by myself while I was working with the bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. And also I don't know how Cantor demonstrated $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equinumerous.

Comment: @Pritam Yes indeed, but the trick of interleaving the digits of the decimal expansion is still a popular approach to this. People often come up with the same idea independently. In this case, it is a well-known trick.

Comment: @Prime I understand. Also what is the function that you would've used  between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: $\frac {\tanh x + 1} 2$ probably, or I'd do a piecewise definition with a reciprocal.